# фильтрация на django

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте, разработчики есть одно проблема я сделал поиск на сайте используя функция .filter()
и все получилось но надо сделать так чтоб пользователь вел несколько строчек опять работал сейчас так что должен целую имя искать чтоб нашёл.

вот мои коды.

```
def post_list(request):
    queryset_list = Post.objects.all()#.order_by("-updated")


    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(title=query)|
            Q(content=query)
        )
```

а вот и форма поиска.

```
<div class="tales-searchbox">
    <form action="" method="GET" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <button class="searchbutton" type="submit" >
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search serche"></i>
        </button>
        <input class="searchfield" id="searchbox" type="text"
        name="q" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
</div>
```

буду очень благодарен если поможете :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы искать не точное совпадение по словам, а вхождения, Вам надо заменить `title=query` на `title__contains=query` (регистрозависимая проверка на вхождение) либо `на title__icontains=query` (регистро-независимая проверка на вхождение). Во втором случае написание букв (заглавная, или строчная) не будет учитываться.

Comment: Спасибо большое я вам так благодарен !!!

Comment: @ArenAtabekyan, отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как решение, если он является достаточным решением Вашего вопроса

Comment: Как ?....................

Comment: @ArenAtabekyan, слева от ответа галочка (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)